# Applications of KMP failure function

Tags: string, algorithm

Many articles on KMP mention that the failure function in KMP itself has a large number of applications.

One such application is finding the smallest string which when concatenated k times gives the original string(period).

But I could not find any other. What other problems involve the KMP failure function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

KMP computes the **borders** of all prefixes of a string, which are themselves a key notion in algorithm on strings. (Computing the border of the whole word itself is nontrivial, and KMP (failure function) is the standard for doing that!)

A border of *s* is simply any word that is both a prefix and suffix of *s*.

As you rightly noticed, an outstanding application of the ability to compute borders is the possibility to compute the smallest string w such that for some natural k *w*^k = *s* for a given string *s*. This is called the **primitive root** of s.

The reason for this is the duality between borders and periods of a string. A **period** of a string *s* is any string *w* no longer than *s* such that *s* is the prefix of the string *wwww*... For example, ***abc*** is a period of ***abcabcab***. It turns out that there is a 1:1 correspondence between borders and periods of a word; in the above example, note that ***abcab*** is a border of ***abcabcab***. In general, whenever *w* is a period of *s*, then the string that remains from *s* after removing *w* from its beginning (*w*^-1 *s*) is a border of *s*. Similarly, if *w* is a border of *s*, then the word that remains from *s* when you remove the suffix *w* is a period of *s*.

Periods are an important tool in analyzing the properties of strings. They are used for example in the algorithms for finding repetitions (runs) in strings; for an overview see [this paper.](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&ved=0CFYQFjAC&url=http://www.mimuw.edu.pl/~rytter/MYPAPERS/Crochemore-Ilie-Rytter.pdf&ei=pN8pUJGaMYiriQLJ_YCAAg&usg=AFQjCNGwzSajRkMu3uGYN6eskLeFspRTyQ&sig2=bp1qD6484y63D-geG-xTIA&cad=rja)